# Qt example named Boxes working on Ubuntu but not on Windows (Qt 5.0.2)

Tags: windows, qt, opengl, ubuntu, cross-platform

I have been searching for a cross platform GUI application development framework  (Same code for building Linux, Android, Windows apps and OS X) and I found Qt is best for that (Inspired because VLC media player is build with Qt).

First installed it in Ubuntu I had some problem in building examples but I managed to solve it and every examples given in Qt is working fine.

But in Windows every example is working except the "Boxes" example.
[image]

Issues:

```
warning: Qt was built with ANGLE, which provides only OpenGL ES 2.0 on top of DirectX 9.0c
error: This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl desktop
```

**After installing Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 476 MB)**

```
error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.
```

So, I checked Build & Run Option and it shows
[image]

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the Qt Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem **resolved** after installing :

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
2. Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 476 MB)

But, running the program form Qt alone works when I open the compiled exe file it shows `Qt5***.dll` missing.

**Solving missing dll :**

Open compiled `exe` in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and it will show all missing dll. Now go to 
`\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin`
there we can find all Qt5***.dll copy it and past it in `exe` location.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have qt built with opengl desktop option.

http://qt-project.org/downloads

look for `Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 476 MB)`

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-msvc2010_32_opengl-x86-offline.exe.mirrorlist

after installing this qt release your example should work

Comment: As you said I installed Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 476 MB) and now I am getting
`:-1: error: Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Configure a compiler in the kit options.`